# Automated build for MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Has anyone had success setting up automated builds for MATLAB code?  We are manually compiling our MATLAB code into EXE's and distributing them to our servers.  If anyone has found a good way to automate this, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

By "manually compiling" do you mean using mcc directly or are you already using deploytool?

Answer (score 0):

Most build servers can automate the execution of a executable file.  So simply use the build server to automate the build by calling the mcc.exe compiler and then handling its output...